# How can a Project administrator give work item only view access to a user

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

If I understand correctly, there are membership groups at three levels in TFS - SERVER, COLLECTION and PROJECT, with different security settings for each.

A user without a CAL presumably must, directly or indirectly, be a member of a SERVER level group which has the permission "Use full Web Access features" set to Deny, such as the built-in group "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\Work Item Only View Users". However,

- a PROJECT administrator cannot edit the membership of SERVER level
  groups, and
- a SERVER level group cannot contain PROJECT or COLLECTION
  level groups.

So how is it possible for a PROJECT administrator to give a user this limited access? The example scenarios I've found all suggest that a SERVER administrator must first add the user to a SERVER group with the correct permissions set, then the PROJECT administrator must add the same user to the PROJECT Contributors group, i.e. the user has to be added twice by two different people.

Ironically, a PROJECT administrator can give a user full access to a project by simply adding them to the Contributors group. This seems to be completely the wrong way round. Surely it should be possible for the PROJECT administrator to give limited access directly, with full access only being granted by the SERVER administrator, once it has been verified that the new user has a valid CAL.

If anyone knows how I can give a PROJECT administrator the ability to grant work item only access to a project without the SERVER admin needing to do anything, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Access Level is set at the Instance level, go to the http://[yourserver]:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses URL to see it.

It control TFS functionality available (say menu options) not the object one have access to.
Two user may have the same right on a work item, but one is able to manage in the Agile Portfolio Management, the other is not.